# How to hide the label of a diagram link in Enterprise Architect using Add-in?

Tags: enterprise-architect

In Enterprise Architect, user can hide/show the labels of links (connectors) on a diagram. Concerning extension (add-in) development for EA, is there a **function** that calling it can **set the visibility of a label** on the diagram(s)?

Or in another more general word, how is it possible to retrieve the **list of the labels** of a connector **programmatically**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manipulate the `diagramLinks.Geometry` property. When you have a label this string will contain something like

```
LMT=CX=6:CY=13:OX=42:OY=9:HDN=0:BLD=0:ITA=0:UND=0:CLR=-1:ALN=0:DIR=0:ROT=0;
```

`LMT` is the part for the middle label which contains the name. `LMB` is for the stereotype and other `L`-attributes are for roles and cardinality.

Now you need to change `HDN=0` to `HDN=1` to make the label invisible.