# Enterprise Architect script not updating diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a JScript in Enterprise Architect which should hide some connector labels by setting the "HDN" attribute of the geometry property of the DiagramLinks to 1 according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28810123:

```
// Get a reference to the current diagram
var currentDiagram as EA.Diagram;
currentDiagram = Repository.GetCurrentDiagram();

if (currentDiagram != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < currentDiagram.DiagramLinks.Count; i++)
    {
        var currentDiagramLink as EA.DiagramLink;
        currentDiagramLink = currentDiagram.DiagramLinks.GetAt(i);

        currentDiagramLink.Geometry = currentDiagramLink.Geometry
            .replace(/HDN=0/g, "HDN=1")
            .replace(/LLT=;/, "LLT=HDN=1;")
            .replace(/LRT=;/, "LRT=HDN=1;");
        if (!currentDiagramLink.Update())
        {
            Session.Output(currentDiagramLink.GetLastError());
        }
    }
}
```

However, the diagram is not updated (the view does not change). Am I missing something?

When executing the script a second time, I can see in the debugger, that the new Geometry values are still there, but they don't seem to get applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diagrams do not get updated on any element change (well, usually and in most cases; this is EA). You need to reload changed diagrams with

```
Repository.ReloadDiagram (currentDiagram.DiagramID);
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped with updating the view! Yet another question, maybe you know it, too: Actually, I only want to hide the source and target "top label" parts of the connectors, not the "bottom labels". However, the Geometry property looks exactly the same for both cases if I do it manually. Do you know how to achieve this programmatically?

Comment: You should ask a new question for that. I'll have a look later the evening then. Should be possible.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44889397/3775882