# Enterprise Architect: Hide only "top" labels of connectors programmatically

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to hide the "top" part of all connector labels of a diagram. For this, I tried to set up a script, but it currently hides ALL labels (also the "bottom" labels which I want to preserve):

```
// Get a reference to the current diagram
var currentDiagram as EA.Diagram;
currentDiagram = Repository.GetCurrentDiagram();

if (currentDiagram != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < currentDiagram.DiagramLinks.Count; i++)
    {
        var currentDiagramLink as EA.DiagramLink;
        currentDiagramLink = currentDiagram.DiagramLinks.GetAt(i);

        currentDiagramLink.Geometry = currentDiagramLink.Geometry
            .replace(/HDN=0/g, "HDN=1")
            .replace(/LLT=;/, "LLT=HDN=1;")
            .replace(/LRT=;/, "LRT=HDN=1;");
        if (!currentDiagramLink.Update())
        {
            Session.Output(currentDiagramLink.GetLastError());
        }
    }
}
```

When I hide only the top labels manually (context menu of a connector/Visibility/Set Label Visibility), the Geometry property of the DiagramLinks remains unchanged, so I guess the detailed label visibility information must be contained somewhere else in the model.

Does anyone know how to change my script?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The dialog for editing the detailed label visibility looks as follows:
[image: Enterprise Architect Label Visibility Dialog]

My goal is unchecking the "top label" checkboxes programmatically.

Comment: Can you clarify with a picture what exactly you mean by "top part"?

Comment: I have added an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Geometry` attribute you will find a partial string like

```
LLT=CX=36:CY=13:OX=0:OY=0:HDN=0:BLD=0:ITA=0:UND=0:CLR=-1:ALN=1:DIR=0:ROT=0;
```

So in between `LLT` and the next semi-colon you need to locate the `HDN=0` and replace that with `HDN=1`. A simple global change like above wont work. You need a wild card like in the regex `LLT=([^;]+);` to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I need to set HDN to 1 ONLY for LLT and LRT, not globally. I solved it with this replacement code: `currentDiagramLink.Geometry = currentDiagramLink.Geometry
    .replace(/(LLT=[^;]*HDN)=0([^;]*;)/, "$1=1$2")
    .replace(/(LRT=[^;]*HDN)=0([^;]*;)/, "$1=1$2")
    .replace(/LLT=;/, "LLT=HDN=1;")
    .replace(/LRT=;/, "LRT=HDN=1;");`